# Citymaps SDK android, can't add tiles layer

Tags: android, dictionary, citymaps

I’m developer. I starting with an application from SDK by Citymaps.
I read from here: http://developer.citymaps.com/layers#data-layer
However, SDK version latest not support like this, i writing like:

```
DataTileSource tileSource = DataTileSource.createFromURL("http://vector.mapzen.com/osm/all/{zoom}/{x}/{y}.json”);

// Initialize the layer
TileLayerOptions optionsTiles = new TileLayerOptions(tileSource);

DataTileLayer dataLayer = new DataTileLayer(optionsTiles);
// Object implementing the interface

DataTileLayerListener dataLayer.setListener(this);
 // Add the layer to the map

mapView.setBaseLayer(dataLayer);.
```

With interface “DataTileLayerListener” i listener event “onTileLoaded” and it’s print to logger “working”…  but Tiles map not show on View.

Can u help me? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the lead developers on the Citymaps Maps team and I'd be happy to help with your issue.

I think you are confused as to the functionality of the DataTileLayer.  Data layers do not actually have any specific parsing or rendering behavior.  They simply return the data, as is, to the client application.  Any parsing or rendering of that data must be handled by the client.  Additionally, the data layer will not manage the data for you, so if you have features that should be added or removed when a tile comes on or off screen, it is up to the client to handle that as well.

I took a quick look at the data you are trying to parse.  It seems to be returning a GeoJSON data set.  If you write a GeoJSON parser (at this time, Citymaps does not ship with this feature), you can then render these features using a CanvasLayer.  You can read more about CanvasLayer here: http://developer.citymaps.com/canvas

Rather than using Mapzen's vector tiles for your base layer, I would recommend using a Citymaps vector layer, which you can use by initializing a CitymapsMapView.  This does, however, require an API key.  If you would like an API key, follow the instructions here: http://developer.citymaps.com/getting-started#apikey

Comment: Thanks u. I had API_KEY. I'm trying use it.